# What's the best way to include RSS feeds in my wordpress sidebar?

Tags: wordpress, rss, themes, sidebar

I have a small network of sites, and on site "A", I'd like to include a sidebar code to display recent posts from the rest of my network, minus site "A".

I've seen widgets that possibly do this, but I don't use widgets in my theme.

I'd like to include:

URL, Title, Blog Name possibly, and Thumbnail Image.

You can actually see an example at this site:  http://boston.barstoolsports.com/  (warning, not very SFW)

On the sidebar he lists "Around Bartsool" which is pretty similar to what I'm aiming at.

Thanks for any suggestions

Comment: Here's a start: http://www.wprecipes.com/how-to-display-any-rss-feed-on-your-wordpress-blog

Comment: Thanks, that's close but it doesn't really allow me to customize the links at all that I can see.  Ie, pulling thumbnails, site titles, etc

Comment: This will get you a bit further. `fetch_feed` retrieves a given RSS feed, which you can parse as you like. http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/fetch_feed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this plugin will add featured images to your RSS:
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-rss-images/

then just look for a competent RSS reader
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/
don't know if this is what you need?
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/miro-hristov-rss-reader/faq/